# PHP NGINX STOPS WORKING ON WINDOWS AFTER A PERIOD OF TIME

Tags: php, windows, nginx, webserver

I am facing a weird issue on windows machine. I am using php-cgi and nginx to run my php project. Everything works fine for a specific period of time like for example 15 to 20 hours then php-cgi and nginx both services stopped working. This happens repeatedly when I start the services again. Please check below is my bat file content.

Bat file content:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Starting PHP FastCGI...
SET PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=0
start C:\webserver\nginx\nginx.exe
C:\RunHiddenConsole.exe C:\webserver\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c "C:\werbserver\php.ini"
```